# Insert an advanced formula into a cell

Tags: vba, excel

Using Excel 2016 I am struggling to get a formula pasted into a cell with VBA (where the VBA does a data import). I have two sheets: `Rapport SNN` and `Data`.

```
Sheets("Rapport SNN").[E4].Formula = "=SUMIFS(Data!S2:Data!S2000;Data!V2:Data!V2000;""BankAxept"";Data!M2:Data!M2000;C4)/100"
```

Just throws me a:

> Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: use commas as a separator rather than semi-columns

Comment: @nutsch, in locals where the comma is the decimals separator, semicolons are used as argument separators

Comment: @SeanC, yes but not in VBA, except if you use `.FormulaLocal`

Comment: Easiest way to get the formula written correctly is to record a macro while you type the formula in the excel spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have semicolons when they should be commas.

```
WorkSheets("Rapport SNN").[E4].Formula = "=SUMIFS(Data!S2:Data!S2000,Data!V2:Data!V2000,""BankAxept"",Data!M2:Data!M2000,C4)/100"
```

Comment: in locals where the comma is the decimals separator, semicolons are used as argument separators

Comment: OH. That's good to know. OP, are you using US version of excel?

Comment: semicolumns will not work on the VBA side, except if you use `.FormulaLocal`

Comment: @SeanC - THANK YOU! It was the FormulaLocale that sorted it :)

Yes, I use the US version.

But then, I would like to add a loop to this line as it need to populate E4 through E20 where the C4 at the end of the formula equals the row of E; example where it would be [E5] it should say C5 etc.

This can me done within a loop/count?