# Need to put multiple values from VBA to cells using loop/for

Tags: vba, excel

Referring to a previos question that now has turned to something more advanced ([Insert an advanced formula into a cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33311606/insert-an-advanced-formula-into-a-cell/33312229?noredirect=1#comment54467228_33312229));

I have created a list using Me.TerminalID1 (through 14).List to populate 14 dropdown lists in my UserForm where reach drowndown is named cboTerminalID1 through 14.

I want to use a loop function to add the content from cboTerminalID1 through 14 to populate cells inside Excel, C4 through C17.

I've tried this code; but it obvious not work;

```
    For TIDtoCell = 4 To 17 Step 1
    Sheets("Rapport SNN").[C & TIDtoCell & ].FormulaLocal = "=cboTerminalID" & TIDtoCell & ""
    Next TIDtoCell
```

The idea is that it should be;

Sheets("Rapport SNN").[C4].FormulaLocal =cboTerminalID4

Any ideas ? So hopeless to be a newbie...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the comboboxes contain formulas that you wish to write to the worksheet:

```
For TIDtoCell = 4 To 17
    Sheets("Rapport SNN").Cells(TIDtoCell, 3).FormulaLocal = "=" & Me.Controls("cboTerminalID" & TIDtoCell - 3)
Next
```

Note: this also assumes that the formulas, as stored in the comboboxes, do not include the initial equal sign.

Note: this assumes this code will be placed into the userform code module.

If any of these assumptions are incorrect, I am happy to alter the answer. Just let me know.

**UPDATE**

Based on new information that the values in the comboboxes are not formulas, this is the solution:

```
For TIDtoCell = 4 To 17
    Sheets("Rapport SNN").Cells(TIDtoCell, 3) = Me.Controls("cboTerminalID" & TIDtoCell - 3).Value
Next
```

Comment: I possibly didnt explain good enough. It is the Value of cboTerminalID I want to put into the cell.

I've rewritten the code a bit, and got to the point where it put the same value in every cell C4-C17:

`Set RapportSheet = Worksheets("Rapport SNN")
Dim TIDtoCell As Integer
            For TIDtoCell = 4 To 17 Step 1
                RapportSheet.Range("C" & TIDtoCell & "").Value = cboTerminalID1.Value`

I've tried to set `=cboTerminalID(TIDtoCell).Value and =cboTerminalID & TIDtoCell & .Value`, but I get error all the time.

Comment: So the values in the comboboxes are not formulas?

Comment: Correct, I misunderstood what I needed to put in and the term (I've worked with VBA since past thursday so please forgive my mistake). It is the chosen value from the dropdownlist I need to pass. If I do just one single cell I got it working by `RapportSheet.Range("C4").Value = cboTerminalID1.Value`

Comment: It worked! May I ask so I learn and understand, how the .Cells(TIDtoCell, 3) put the value in C4, as I don't see any reference to colum C ?

Comment: The Cells() method of the worksheet object allows you to reference all of the sheet's cells numerically. The first parameter to Cells() is the row index. The second is the column index. Column 3 is column C.

Comment: @StighAarstein Please feel free to up-vote my answer... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
For TIDtoCell = 4 To 17 Step 1
    Sheets("Rapport SNN").["C" & TIDtoCell].FormulaLocal = "=cboTerminalID" & TIDtoCell & ""
Next TIDtoCell
```